# Select a number of rows in a dataframe after a valid condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I would like to select a specified number of lines after a condition is verified:

- Here is my dataframe :

[image]

- I would like to select three columns after the entry is equal to 1, *so for the first occurrence* I would obtain something like that :

[image]

- I don't know what's the most appropriate output if I want to study every occurrence, maybe a groupby ?

Comment: What if there is another 1 directly after a 1 (or closeby). What does this do to your expected output?

Comment: @JvdV there cannot be a 1 right after a 1 (but two lines after it's possible), I does not affect my output because it's what I want to study.

Comment: @JvdV to be more precise on what I want to do, I will add a 1 in another column if in my output there is no other 1 (in my occurrence) but I think I can manage that after this output here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First remove `0` rows before first `1`:

```
df = df[df['entry'].eq(1).cumsum().ne(0)]

df = df.groupby(df['entry'].cumsum()).head(4)
    Timestamp  entry
1        11.2      1
2        11.3      0
3        11.4      0
4        11.5      0
7        11.8      1
8        11.9      0
9        12.0      0
10       12.1      0
```

**Details & explanation**:

For general solution for remove all values before first match is used compare by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html), then cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and compare by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) - so filter out all `0` values after `cumsum` operation:

```
print (df.assign(comp1 = df['entry'].eq(1),
                 cumsum =df['entry'].eq(1).cumsum(),
                 mask = df['entry'].eq(1).cumsum().ne(0)))
    Timestamp  entry  comp1  cumsum   mask
0        11.1      0  False       0  False
1        11.2      1   True       1   True
2        11.3      0  False       1   True
3        11.4      0  False       1   True
4        11.5      0  False       1   True
5        11.6      0  False       1   True
6        11.7      0  False       1   True
7        11.8      1   True       2   True
8        11.9      0  False       2   True
9        12.0      0  False       2   True
10       12.1      0  False       2   True
```

After filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) create helper `Series` with cumulative `sum` for groups:

```
print (df['entry'].cumsum())
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     1
7     2
8     2
9     2
10    2
Name: entry, dtype: int64
```

So for final solution use [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) with `4` values for get rows with `1` and next 3 rows:

```
df = df.groupby(df['entry'].cumsum()).head(4)
print (df)
    Timestamp  entry
1        11.2      1
2        11.3      0
3        11.4      0
4        11.5      0
7        11.8      1
8        11.9      0
9        12.0      0
10       12.1      0
```

---

For loop by groups use:

```
for i, g in df.groupby(df['entry'].cumsum()): 
    print (g.head(4))
```

If want output list of `DataFrame`s:

```
L = [g.head(4) for i, g in df.groupby(df['entry'].cumsum())]
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I understand what you did, but I would like to access every occurrence, I thought that you could use groupby in a for loop so what I will be able to work on every occurrence at the time but when I put your groupby in a loop it does not work ...

Comment: yes it's better thanks, but why can't you put the head(4) in the loop statement : *in df.groupby(df['entry'].cumsum().head(4))* ?
By the way, I think you wrote x instead of g in the last edit

Comment: @Lukx - thanks. So reason is because `df.groupby(df['entry'].cumsum().head(4))` return DataFrame and you need loop by groups, not by dataframe.